# Combination of two ParametricPlot in one plot?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I have two `ParametricPlot` in the following form:

```
ParametricPlot[{1 + (3*t^2)/2 - t^4/24, 4*t - t^3/3}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

and

```
ParametricPlot[{-(11/48) - (59*t)/48 + (203*t^2)/96 + (59*t^3)/
    288 - (107*t^4)/1152 - (59*t^5)/5760, 
     -(59/48) + (251*t)/48 + (59*t^2)/96 - (155*t^3)/288 - (59*t^4)/
    1152 + (59*t^5)/5760}, {t, 1, 3/2}]
```

I want to have one plot in `0<t<3/2`.

Comment: You might want to use `Piecewise[]` for this.

Comment: @J. M. If possible for you, please help about Piecewise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what J.M. is suggesting

```
f[t_] = Piecewise[
      {{{1 + (3*t^2)/2 - t^4/24, 4*t - t^3/3}, 0 < t < 1},
      {{-(11/48) - (59*t)/48 + (203*t^2)/96 + (59*t^3)/ 288 - (107*t^4)/1152 
       - (59*t^5)/5760, -(59/48) + (251*t)/ 48 + (59*t^2)/96 - (155*t^3)/288
       - (59*t^4)/1152 + (59*t^5)/ 5760}, 1 < t < 3/2}}]

ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 3/2}, AspectRatio -> 0.5]
```

[image]

(And that's how you steal other's credit ;) )

Comment: :D Thanks for following through.

Comment: what is the problem? and what do you mean by two separate distances?

Answer (score 2):

```
ParametricPlot[
 If[t < 1, {1 + (3*t^2)/2 - t^4/24, 4*t - t^3/3},
           {-(11/48) - (59*t)/48 + (203*t^2)/96 + (59*t^3)/
            288 - (107*t^4)/1152 - (59*t^5)/5760, -(59/48) + (251*t)/
            48 + (59*t^2)/96 - (155*t^3)/288 - (59*t^4)/1152 + (59*t^5)/
            5760}],
               {t, 0, 3/2}]
```

Because of the discontinuity at $t=1$, you may want to add `Exclusions -> 1`.